# How can I drive individual sprites

Tags: python, pygame

I would like individual cars to drive across the screen from left to right with a certain time interval.It should be an endless loop. It is ended by program end
With my code, they all start at the same time. In addition, rect.y changes from the default value 300 to 0.

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = []
        for i in range(5):
            img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/quer_auto_{i}.png")   
            self.images.append(img) 
           
        self.image = self.images[random.randrange(0, 5)]     
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()             
        self.rect.x = 100
        self.rect.y = 300       
        self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.delay = 5000

    def update(self): 

        self.rect.x += 5
        current = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current - self.last > self.delay:
            self.last = current               
            self.image = self.images[random.randrange(0, 5)]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = 100  
 
background = pygame.image.load("Bilder/starfield.png") 
background_rect = background.get_rect()


cars = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(3):
            m = Car()            
            cars.add(m)

running = True
while running:   
    clock.tick(FPS)  
    for event in pygame.event.get():       
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False        
    
    cars.update() 
   
    screen.fill((250,250,250))
    screen.blit(background,background_rect)
    cars.draw(screen)
  
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you want these cars to be robots) First create variable and lets name them `car_move_right` and `car_move_left` . If you want the car to move towards the right at the beginning of the game, set the `car_move_right` to True and the other variable to False, and vice versa. Then in the main loop, add an `if` statement like this:

(Taking carX to be X-coordinate of car)

```
if car_move_right:
    carX += ai_move_speed
    if carX == WINDOWWIDTH or carX > WINDOWWIDTH:
        car_move_right = False
        car_move_left = True          



if car_move_left:
    carX -= ai_move_speed
    if carX == 0 or carX < 0:
        car_move_left = False
        car_move_right = True
```

Please note: I had written this code for robot movement which also included going up and down. Not the cleanest and best, but I think it would work for you.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not my problem. I want that car by car are starting with a little delay between the single cars. Here in my code, they start all at the same time. Later, when a car exceeds the end of the screen, I will kill it.

Comment: Your question was not too explanatory, but alright. A little delay can be made with `pygame.time.get_ticks()`, not too hard. And by kill I assume you want it to disappear, not problem let me write another answer.

Comment: How many cars are there @Joachim ?

Comment: i work with 10 carss

Comment: Why is the car moving so fast?

Comment: oh sorry saw your comments just now. So um I forgot to mention but you should create a variable named `ai_move_speed` and give it any value you want. And for 10 cars, sorry man but I never worked with classes or too complicated functions, etc. But I can give you a tip : see my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

rect.y changes to 0 because you reset the rect, and default rect's x and y values are 0.

```
   if current - self.last > self.delay:
        self.last = current               
        self.image = self.images[random.randrange(0, 5)]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() ##<--- here
        self.rect.x = 100
```

Also you should consider storing your car's position in a python variable, since `self.rect.x` can only store integers.

For the timer thing, you should move your update function outside of your car class since it does not have any information about other cars and it needs it.

Here is an example implementation.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50)).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()             
        self.rect.x = 100
        self.rect.y = 300

    def finished(self):
        return self.rect.x >= WIDTH - self.rect.width

class Driver:
    def __init__(self, cars):
        self.cars = cars
        self.currentCar = 0
        self.delay = 1000
        self.current = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.timePassed = False

    def updateCar(self, car):
        if self.timePassed:
            car.rect.x += 1 #5

    def runTimer(self):
        self.current = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.timePassed = False
        if self.current - self.last > self.delay:
            self.timePassed = True

    def Run(self):
        self.runTimer()
        car = self.cars.sprites()[self.currentCar]
        if not car.finished():
            self.updateCar(car)
        else:
            self.current = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.currentCar += 1

    def allFinished(self):
        return self.currentCar >= len(self.cars)

cars = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(3):
    m = Car()            
    cars.add(m)
    
driver = Driver(cars)
            
while True:

    if not driver.allFinished():
        driver.Run()

    #btw, no need to fill if you have background image the size of window
    screen.fill((250,250,250))
    
    #screen.blit(background,background_rect)
    cars.draw(screen)
  
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create 10 car classes. Give them a different name, like `car1`, `car2`, etc.
2. Let's focus on `car1` for now. Let `car1X` represent the x-coordinate of `car1`.
3. Now for the speed of movement. If you want each car to have the same speed, just create a variable named `ai_move_speed`. Now, if you want the speed to differ, then instead of `ai_move_speed`, make 10 variables and name these variables as `ai1_move_speed`, `ai2_move_speed`, etc. For now, set these variables to an integer value of 2.
4. For the movement of left to right, create a variable called `car1_move_right` and set it to True.
5. As each car will go from left to right, then die, We can simply add this code to our main loop :

`if car1_move_right:`

`car1X += ai_move_speed`

Now once the game is run, `car1` will go from its x-coordinate towards the left side. Repeat this process for the other cars.

But if you want the cars to go back to their original position if they go out of the boundary or die, then just add this line of code at the end of the above code:

```py
if carX == 800:
   carX = 100
```

6. Now so far we fixed movement. Now if you want the cars to start 1 after the other, delete the entire code from before. Now you can customize when a car starts. For `car1` let's simply create a variable and call this variable `c1_time`. Set it to 5000 for now. Now I want to introduce you to a pygame function called `pygame.time.get_ticks()`. It gets the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` has been called in milliseconds. Remember the `c1_time`? We set it to an integer value of 5000 because 1000 milliseconds is 1 second, so `car1` will start moving after 5 seconds after the interpreter reads `pygame.init()`.
7. Now create this variable : `time_init` and store this code inside it : `pygame.time.get_ticks()`. After that create an `if` statement as so :

```
if car1_move_right:
     if time_init >= c1_time:
         car1X += ai_move_speed
     if car1X == 800:
         car1X = 100
```

Now what this above code does is that 5 seconds after the game starts, it will start moving `car1`. If car1 goes out of boundary it gets it back again. Repeat these steps for the other cars. This is the simplest and bug-free way I could do it.

PS - Feel free to change any variable name. Just make sure to change it everywhere in the code.

PPS - Please read the entire thing. Also upvote if you found this helpful cuz I spent a lot of time on this.